# Пересчет динамически добавляемых элементов в DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

Имеется произвольный список строк из `n` позиций в таблице:

```
<table id="mytab">
    <tr>1</tr>
    <tr>2</tr>
    ...
    <tr>n</tr>
</table>
```

Далее js-код, который подсчитывает количество строк и разбивает их постранично например по 10 штук, это происходит при загрузке страницы. При добавлении или удалении строки ajax-запросом все содержимое `tbody` переписывается путем вывода из базы данных с учетом изменений добавления или удаления строки. При этом постраничный вывод нарушается и выводится сразу весь список. Я предполагаю, что это связано с заменой старых `tr` на новые `tr`. Прав ли я и как это исправить?

Comment: Конечно можно каждый раз заново вызывать функцию пагинации, но можно ли как-то более элегантно решить проблему?

Comment: чудес не бывает. ему надо дать команду пересчитать пагинацию

Comment: можете использовать данный плагин для работы с таблицей — http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager Он умеет работать с пагинацией + ajax